# Unable to install PrimeNg on Angular 12.1.4. npm Error

Tags: angular, npm, primeng

I am trying to add PrimeNg to my Project however, I get this strange error, I am not sure how to fix it. Can anyone help me out? The current version of angular installed in my machine is 12.1.4.

```
205-185-99-116:$ npm install primeng --save
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 

npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@12.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   @angular/common@"^12.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/common@"^7.0.0 || ^8.0.0 || ^9.0.0 || ^10.0.0 || ^11.0.0" from primeng@11.4.5
npm ERR! node_modules/primeng
npm ERR!   primeng@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its complaining about peer dependencies. This should work:

```
npm install primeng --save --force
```

Comment: why do we need force

Answer (score 2):

You might want to avoid giving --force flag. This issue is due to version mismatch. If you install using --force, it would cause the application to behave weirdly in many cases.
Your Angular version is 12, primeng version (default, when you give npm i primeng --save) is 11.4. You might want to try installing 12.0.1 version.

Comment: Thanks, for the heads up. Will try that, definitely.